# Errors when move files using mv on CentOs

Tags: linux, centos6, mv

I am moving files from my CentOs disk to mounted USB drive as `root`.

My **current working directory is** `/mnt/hdd/backup`my command is :

`mv -v /home/haifzhan/20141215/*gz . > history.log`

Error Messages on console:

```
mv: cannot create regular file `./20141215/filename_xxx.gz': Input/output error
mv: writing `./20141215/filename_yyy.gz': Input/output error
```

My tracking history log in history.log that create by `-v` by command `mv`:

```
`/home/haifzhan/20141215/filename_xxx.gz' -> `./20141215/filename_xxx.gz'
`/home/haifzhan/20141215/filename_yyy.gz' -> `./20141215/filename_yyy.gz'
```

The destination folder details:

```
drwx------. 2 root   root          319488 May 13 16:46 20141215
```

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: From the output it is trying to move the file onto itself.

Comment: I said my current directory is `/mnt/hdd/backup` ,  trying to move from `/home/haifzhan/20141215` to `/mnt/hdd/backup/20141215`

Comment: @JohnBollinger  If move the file onto itself, it will say something like this: `mv: ‘sample.csv’ and ‘./sample.csv’ are the same file`

Comment: I assume you checked the permissions source directory as well?

Comment: I am running the command as `root`, the source directory permission is `drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 454656 Dec 17 07:04 20141215`, based on the error messages, it is kind of `writing` issue

Comment: Check the system log for any kernel messages pertaining to the I/O error.

Comment: It looks like you successfully wrote one file (plus the log file), but failed to write the next file.  This may be a sign of filesystem corruption or hardware failure.  If you have a filesystem scanner for the target filesystem type (e.g. `fsck` for ext[234]) then consider unmounting the filesystem and scanning it for errors.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  Thanks John. I checked `/var/log/messages`, I found `Sense Key : Medium Error [current] `  it seems like the USB drive corrupted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger John, with your help I figured out the mounted hard driver is broken. You can edit your comment and write it as an answer, then I will check it, thanks for your help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

An "Input/output error" suggests a problem with hardware or filesystem, as indeed proved to be the case here.  Upon seeing such an error message it is therefore a good idea to check for more details in the system log, and possibly to run a filesystem integrity check.  Such a message does not normally indicate user error.